# .NET MAUI app crashes EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS

Tags: .net, maui

I have a .NET MAUI app that works flawless on Android but now that I am trying it out on iOS it doesnt work anymore. It has worked before and my guess is that it doesnt find the appicon or splash image. But I cannot find out where it crashes and why. On testflight I get this error:

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016f67fff8
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x000000016f67fff8
VM Region Info: 0x16f67fff8 is in 0x16f67c000-0x16f680000;  bytes after start: 16376  bytes before end: 7
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_SMALL             14f000000-14f800000 [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
      GAP OF 0x1fe7c000 BYTES
--->  STACK GUARD              16f67c000-16f680000 [   16K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  ... for thread 0
      Stack                    16f680000-16f77c000 [ 1008K] rw-/rwx SM=SHM  thread 0
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [23057]
```

I have tried debugging it on a iOS simulator but I dont get an expetion or at least I cannot figure out how to make it log/show me the error in debug. When I try to launch the app it just closes instantly.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards Max

Answer (score 0):

> .NET MAUI app crashes EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS

About this error you can try to add following code settings to your csproj file:

```xml
<MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
<UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
```

For more details you can see this issue: [iOS app crashes using TestFlight #11276](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11276).

Hope it can help you!